# Converge in the space of sequence $l_2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given $$x,y,x^{(n)},y^{(n)}\in l_2$$

with
  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{(n)}=x,\quad\lim_{n\to \infty}y^{(n)}=y$$
does the following is true?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i^{(n)} y_i^{(n)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}  x_i y_i $$

Comment: You probably mean $x_i^{(n)}y_i^{(n)}$ in your summation on the last line.

Comment: @persiad, yes and they are sequenses of sequenses.... x,y are sequenses too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. $\newcommand\inner[2]{\left\langle #1, #2 \right\rangle}$Notice that

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_iy_i = \inner{x}{y}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^{(n)}y_i^{(n)} = \inner{x^{(n)}}{y^{(n)}}$$

so your statement is just the continuity of the inner product on $\ell^2$:

$$\inner{x^{(n)}}{y^{(n)}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \inner{x}{y}$$

We can easily prove it using CSB. Since $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent, there exists $M > 0$ such that $\left\|y^{(n)}\right\|_2 < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

\begin{align}
\left|\inner{x}{y} - \inner{x^{(n)}}{y^{(n)}} \right| &=\left|\inner{x}{y} - \inner{x}{y^{(n)}} + \inner{x}{y^{(n)}} - \inner{x^{(n)}}{y^{(n)}} \right|\\
&\le \left|\inner{x}{y-y^{(n)}}\right| + \left|\inner{x -
 x^{(n)}}{y^{(n)}} \right|\\ 
&\le \|x\|_2 \left\|y-y^{(n)}\right\|_2 + \left\|x - x^{(n)}\right\|_2\left\|y^{(n)}\right\|\\
&= \|x\|_2 \left\|y-y^{(n)}\right\|_2 + M\left\|x - x^{(n)}\right\|_2\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0
\end{align}